# TypeError: Cannot add property providers, object is not extensible NGRX

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

This is happening after I moved to the latest version of NGRX
"@ngrx/component-store": "15.2",
"@ngrx/effects": "15.2.0",
"@ngrx/router-store": "15.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "15.2.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "15.2.0",

```
    users$= createEffect(() => this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(users.LOAD_USERS),
      tap((action: users.LoadUsersAction) => {
        action.item.name = action.payload;
        action.item.id = action.payload.map(item => item.id);
      })));
```

It gives TypeError: Cannot add property name, object is not extensible at both lines at name and id.

Already tried the following approaches none of them worked:-

```
    action.item = {
      ...action.item,
      name: action.payload,
      id: action.payload.map(item => item.id)
----------------------------------
    const newItem = {
      ...action.item,
      name: action.payload,
      id: action.payload.map(item => item.id)
    };
------------------

    action.item = Object.assign({}, action.item, {
      name: action.payload,
      id: action.payload.map(item => item.id)
    });
```

Comment: You can't assign a value to `action`, because it's a parameter, not a variable. Please explain, why do you need to assign a value to `action`?

Comment: This is an existing code in the app. How can I modify it?

Comment: You can create a new property in your class and assign values to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actions (and state) are immutable.
When you're updating properties directly this results in an error.
Ideally you should rewrite the code, but you can also disable these checks.
For more info see https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks

Comment: Disabling the checks is breaking the app. So, I refactored the code. It seems to be working now.